# $\Omega = R$ Show that all one point sets are Borel sets

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

$\Omega = R$ Show that all one point sets are Borel sets.

I would have stated that $A = \{a\} $ can be generated by the countable intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a - \frac{1}{n} , a + \frac{1}{n})$, hence, it can be generated trough countable intersection of open sets. Furthermore, by taking the complement of $R\setminus a = (-\infty,a)\cup (a,\infty)$ we can also generate any one point set through open sets. The property that it can be generated through the union follows by De Morgans Law.

Would this be a correct proof? Thanks!

Comment: looks fine to me, in fact you can show $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \sigma[\{(-\infty,a]:a\in \mathbb{R}\}]$$ by similar arguments see for example Williams' _Prob with martingales_ p17